# How to make grunt serve stop execution on warnings

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I would like all grunt tasks (serve, build, test, etc) to abort when there are any warnings or errors. Currently, I have a few JSHint warnings, and the console says aborted due to warnings, but then it still serves the page. How can I make it stop and not serve anything?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this lib, it looks like it may do what your looking for: https://github.com/goalzen/grunt-fail

Although I just throw a new error, e.g.:

```
throw new Error("Error detected!")
```